# Making a misclassification table in R

Tags: r, classification, r-caret, knn

There's been a few questions about this issue but I haven't been able to find an answer to my problem. After running a `KNN` algorithm, I've created an `"observed"`/`"predicted"` file. `"observed"` are the real events, whereas `"predicted"` are the events as classified by the algorithm. I have multiple files, all of them with a name following the pattern: `"accuracycollar4136*_4136*.0.*.csv"`. Here's a small sample:

```
> sample<-fread("accuracycollar41361_41366.0.8.csv")
> print(sample)
      V1  observed predicted   
  1:   1   Head-up   Grazing       
  2:   2   Head-up   Head-up      
  3:   3   Head-up   Head-up       
  4:   4   Head-up   Head-up       
  5:   5   Head-up   Head-up       
 ---                                                                                                
236: 236   Unknown   Head-up       
237: 237   Unknown   Grazing      
238: 238 Vigilance   Grazing      
239: 239   Unknown   Grazing       
240: 240   Unknown   Head-up
```

I have already calculated different accuracy measures of classification. However here what I would like to do next:

1) Creating a `for`-loop reading each and every `"accuracycollar4136*_4136*.0.*.csv"` file.

2) For every file, I'd like to create a table summarizing missclassifications.

3) Ideally, I'd like to end-up with a percentage/probability table accounting for the proportion of times an event was classified as another one. As an example, let's say `"Head-up"` was classified 80% of times as "`Head-up`", 15% of times as `"Grazing"` and 5% of times as `"Unknown"`. Here's what I had in mind:

```
    class Head-up Vigilance Grazing Unknown etc.. 
  Head-up       %         %       %       %
Vigilance       %         %       %       %
  Grazing       %         %       %       %
  Unknown       %         %       %       %
    etc..       %         %       %       %
```

I've 9 total classes, being `"Head-up"`, `"Grazing"`, `"Browsing"`, `"Vigilance"`, `"Unknown"`, `"Moving"`, `"Grooming"`, `"Fleeing"`, `"Resting"`.

Now, can this be done with `caret` or any other package? If not, is there a relatively simple way to code such process? Could somebody at least put me on the right track?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Considering all your files are in `"your folder"` (and nothing else is)

```
files = as.list(list.files(path = "your folder"))
```

If that's not the case you just need to pass a list of filenames to `files` for the next step to work

```
miss_class = lapply(files, function(x){
  data = read.csv(x)
  prop.table(table(data$observed,data$predicted),margin=1)
})
```

This will generate a list of percentage tables, one for each file in `your folder`. The `margin = 1` means that the percentage table will sum 100% for the rows. You can change it to 2 for columns or remove the argument for a 100% sum of the whole table

Comment: Yes files are in the same folder. Here's what I've tried: `files = as.list(list.files(path = "C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/KNN/41361_by_41365"))

miss_class = lapply(files, function(x){
  data = read.csv("accuracycollar41361_41365",header=T)
  prop.table(table(data$observed,data$predicted),margin=1)
})`

Comment: I got as Error: `Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
 
 Show Traceback
 
 Rerun with Debug
 Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection`

Comment: This is probably happening because there are some files on that folder that are not `.csv`. You could remove them or, if you can generate a vector of filenames in someway (ex. `v = c("accuracycollar41361_41366.0.8.csv","accuracycollar41362_41366.0.8.csv",...)`) just do `files = as.list(v)` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I was wondering however how I could write in csv format the results table I get printed by R? Do I need to creat an object at the begining of the code?

Comment: You could write each individual table with `write.csv(miss_class[[i]],"your_file.csv")` and replacing `i` with the file index. I'm not sure about how would you save them all to the same file, since it depends on how you want them.

Comment: I want independent files, so I guess that sould work. I'm working on writing it as an `for` loop now so let's see how that works.

Answer (score -1):

The function `table()` will work. Here I have written a simple example on how it works:

```
predicted<-c(1,0,0,1)
observed<- c(1,1,0,1)
data<-data.frame(predicted, observed)
table(data)
```